# How do I fix mura issues on my 15 inch retina Macbook Pro with a Samsung display?

Tags: macbook-pro, display

My 2.3 Ghz 15 retina Macbook Pro with a Samsung display, seems to have some "mura" spots on the display.  I have owned this laptop since July, and just recently have become aware of it.

You only really notice the spots on light backgrounds.  It is very hard to see on dark backgrounds.   Is there a remedy which I can perform, or does the panel have to be replaced?

Thanks